# Create menu link to view with argument

Tags: drupal, menu, hyperlink, arguments

I'm trying to use hook_menu to create a link to a view which takes an argument. However if I use the path (in `$items[view-path/%dest]`) that I've already set as the path in the view then the link doesn't appear. I'm guessing there's a path conflict somewhere. Is there a way round this? Or can I use another method to return the view?

I'm using the following code:

```
/**
* implementation of hook_menu().
*/

function sign_custom_menu() {
  $items['view-path/%dest'] = array(
    'title' => 'Link to view',
    'page callback' => 'sign_custom_hello',
    'page arguments' => array(1), //(corrected typo from 'page arguements')
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
    'menu_name' => 'menu-student-links',
  );

  return $items;
}

function dest_to_arg() {
  // would normally be dynamic to get view with correct argument
  $arg = 73;
  return $arg;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

### Addition

```
function sign_custom_hello() {
    //return t('Hello!');
}
```

Comment: You have a typo in your `$items` declaration: there is no 'e' after 'u' in `page arguments`.

Comment: You should show the code for `sign_custom_hello()`; without to see that code is not possible to give the right answer.

Comment: Mark - Thanks for that. I don't think that is the problem - I've tested it and it didn't make any difference. When I change the path however to one different from the view then the link works fine.

Comment: Kiamlaluno - I've add the code, though I don't think this is affecting the link. The link will work when I change the path in $items[view-path/%dest] to a path that is different from the view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to answer my problem. Basically I used a different path to the one I had set in the view and then used views_page() as my "page callback". I passed it the arguments for the view, the page ID and it's own additional arguments to make the view work. I was able to use a wildcard in the menu item to pass to views_page() by using the to_arg() function that works with hook_menu() to pass in wildcards. The 'page arguments' pass in the three arguments. The last argument, "1" is a reference to which position in the path the argument appears (starting from 0).

The working code is:

```
<?php
/**
* implementation of hook_menu().
*/

function sign_custom_menu() {
    $items['view-path/%dest'] = array(
        'title' => 'link to view',
        'page callback' => 'views_page',
        'page arguments' => array('view_name', 'page_1', 1),
        'access callback' => TRUE,
        'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
        'menu_name' => 'menu-student-links',
    );
    return $items;
}

//this function is needed from the "%dest" argument in hook_menu above 

function dest_to_arg() {
    // would normally be dynamic to get view with correct argument
    $arg = 73;
    return $arg;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much experience with wildcard URLs in my custom modules much, but I researched the issue in the Pro Drupal Development book. From what I read in the ["Wildcards and Parameter Replacement" section on page 77](http://books.google.com/books?id=VmZrdGuBZCMC&lpg=PA77&dq=drupal%20wildcard%20and%20parameter%20replacement&pg=PA77#v=onepage&q=drupal%20wildcard%20and%20parameter%20replacement&f=false), I think you may want to use $items['view-path/%'] instead. Using %dest apparently makes drupal look for a dest_load function.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have a copy of this book. On page 79 they show a to_arg function which is used to pass wildcard arguments to the menu item. This is the %dest argument I've put in. This references the dest_to_arg() which passes the argument to the path. It is not possible to use % by itself as Drupal doesn't know what the value is to build the link.

Answer (score 0):

Items that appear in menus can't be created by a wildcard router item: each menu item corresponds to exactly one path. That is, if you have a router item that is `foo/%bar` and `%bar` can have 10 different values, Drupal's menu system isn't going to create 10 new menu items off of one router item definition.

So what you're going to need to do is create a router item for each possible argument ahead of time. Otherwise, you're going to have to look outside Drupal's menu system and think about creating a separate Views block that looks like a menu but is really a Views unordered list of the available options.

To do the former, you need to implement [`hook_menu_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_menu_alter/6) to add your custom router item after everything else, including the wildcard router item you're trying to override. Your custom router item will be more or less the same as the wildcard router item, but with some defaults set that would normally be derived from the wildcard.

For example, if I wanted to create a new router item for `user/1/edit` which overrides the built-in `user/%user_category/edit`, I'd implement `hook_menu_alter()` as so:

```
function mymodule_menu_alter(&$items) {
  // user_edit and user_edit_access expect a user object
  $account = user_load(array('uid' => 1));

  $items['user/1/edit'] = array(
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    'page arguments' => array($account),
    'access arguments' => array($account),
  ) + $items['user/%user_category/edit'];
}
```

In this example, `user/%user_category/edit` calls [`user_edit()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/user_edit/6) and [`user_edit_access()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/user_edit_access/6) for the page and access callbacks, respectively, and they both attempt to use the wildcard. Since there is no wildcard in your router item, you need override the arguments to say "check user 1".

You'll do this for each and every possible value of the wildcard.

But this isn't enough: notice I used `MENU_CALLBACK` instead of `MENU_NORMAL_ITEM`. If you use `MENU_NORMAL_ITEM`, your router item is going to show up in the *Navigation* menu, not in your custom menu, even if you set `menu_name` (I don't know why this is: it *should* work). But you can get around this by using [`menu_link_save()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/menu_link_save/6).

Consider this implementation of [`hook_init()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_init/6):

```
function mymodule_init() {
  $router_path = 'user/1/edit';

  // Check to see if the custom router item has been added to menu_links.
  // This is to ensure the menu has already been rebuilt.
  $router_item = db_fetch_object(db_query("SELECT * FROM {menu_links} WHERE router_path = '%s'", $router_path));

  // Only create a new menu item if the router item exists and it
  // hasn't already been created (it's hidden until created).
  if ($router_item && $router_item->hidden) {  
    $item = array(
      'link_title' => 'Edit Administrator',
      'link_path' => $router_path,
      'menu_name' => 'primary-links',
      'router_path' => $router_path,
      'mlid' => $router_item->mlid,
    );

    // Save the menu item.
    menu_link_save($item);
  }
}
```

In this implementation, it checks to see if the custom router has already been created and hasn't been otherwise modified. If this is true, it creates a menu link in the primary links menu that references your custom router item.

Obviously, since this is in `hook_init()`, it'll perform the check on every page: this is to ensure it fires after the menu is rebuilt. It shouldn't be much of a performance hit, but it's something to keep in mind.

As you can see, it's a long and drawn out process to do this: if you're not going to go the Views fake-menu route, it might be better to just manually create the links yourself.

Comment: Hi Mark, Thank you very much for taking the time to answer my query. I managed to find an easier way to solve the problem which uses wildcards (see below). It is documented here: http://drupal.org/node/109153#to_arg. There was also a useful example here: http://drupal.org/node/462684.

Comment: Hi Mark, I was googling around to figure out why my menu items kept getting assigned to 'navigation' instead of 'menu-custom'. For some reason if you explicitly set the type to MENU_NORMAL_ITEM, it automatically uses 'navigation' as the target menu. However, MENU_NORMAL_ITEM is the default type. If you set the menu_name and do not set type, the menu will appear in the correct place.